# Review of Differential and Integral Calculus in 60 hours

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

Hopefully this question isn't too narrow. It is similar yet distinct from  this: [Calculus Review On The Web](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109252/calculus-review-on-the-web) and this: [What are some good resources to review basic university calculus, years later?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606146/what-are-some-good-resources-to-review-basic-university-calculus-years-later)

I am looking for a review of differential and integral calculus, preferably video, preferably not longer than about 60 hours for both.

Khan academy, seems much longer than this.

A selection of important lectures on Khan academy, or another site that is free and user friendly, would suffice.

Some identifying characteristics of the material suggested would also be appreciated.

Note: although I am focusing on video content, I would appreciate references to useful texts; free or otherwise, as well.

Comment: What is your purpose in reviewing? (This might help inform the suggestions.)

Comment: @AustinMohr preparation for multivariate calculus and differential equations.

Comment: Paul's math notes is pretty good and you could read threw at your own pace to meet your goal http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx

Comment: Try [mathinsight.org](http://www.mathinsight.org/thread/calculus_refresher).  They also have really good stuff on multivariable when you get to it.

Comment: @Bye_World Thanks to all for suggestions. I am looking forward to investigating them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a brief review of differential and integral calculus and are not too concerned with rigor a better site for you might be the [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com). Physicists tend to adopt a no-nonsense approach to the calculus that gets you there faster. Many mathematics courses often get bogged down in the gory details of the epsilon-delta approach so as to do everything rigorously.  There is also a [rigorous approach based on infinitesimals](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html) but this might be too detailed for you as well.  In short, it depends on your goals.